# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE working via terminal but not cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a PHP script that uses `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` using a `csv file`.

The script downloads and stores the csv file into the same location as the script and then executes a query to insert the csv using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

The location of both csv and php script is outside `public_html` if that matters.

When I run the script as a **cron job**, it runs, downloads the csv (and stores in correct location) but **does not insert** into the DB. The query returns **false**.

If I open the **terminal** and run the script, it downloads the csv and **inserts** into the DB. The query returns **true**.

Would there be a difference between running it in the terminal and running it via cron?

Here is the cron line:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/my_crons/csvfile/csvdownload.php
```

**NOTE**: I have other cron scripts that insert data into a database correctly but this is the only one using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Maybe it's an issue with that command.

Comment: Check for mysql errors after running the query to find out why it failed.

Comment: Sorry, should have been the first thing I did. Yep seems like LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE was forbidden. I thought I enabled it through WHM but it seems that my cron job looking into my home directory was using a different php version and I had to enable mysqli.allow_local_infile for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As aynber pointed out, I should have added some error checking to see the error message from MySQL.

Once I did, the error was as follows:

```
Error description: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile
```

This was strange to me as I thought I had enabled it through WHM using the PHP Editor. However, I noticed that my cron jobs were using a different PHP version and it needed to be enabled there. Once enabled, it fixed the issue.

I had to add to php.ini:

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```